# How to display an image in the webpage in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML/JavaScript. I'd like to display an image to the webpage. I have the image file in the same folder as the .html webpage.

But somehow the image doesn't show up on the webpage. I am not sure why and what I did wrongly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVgEh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0shwM.png)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow as well. How can I attach an image here?

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: Your problem is caused by a typo. The attribute name is `src` which is short for source, not `scr` which is short for screensaver. Using [a validator](https://validator.nu/) would have highlighted this error for you.

Comment: src=your link; also: do not use image to show your code, we can not type the whole code for you. Please show the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using the correct attribute:
use src= not scr=

this is a short form of 'source'

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: You are absolutely right! How silly I am!!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I was trying to delete this question as you suggested. However I get this message: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.